# $rootScope is undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-rootscope

I am getting very strange issue in angular. I have defined $rootScope.user_info in run method. But when i am fetching the root scope in controller, sometimes i am getting undefined method $rootScope.user_info in controller. any idea why this is happen sometimes when i refresh a page?

Here is the code snippets,

```
myApp.run(['$http', '$rootScope','$location','localStorageService','$window','$translate','$timeout', function($http, $rootScope,$location,localStorageService,$window,$translate,$timeout) {
    $rootScope.current_user_id = localStorageService.get("CurrentUserId");
    $rootScope.get_user_profile = function() {
        $http.get('/api/v1/employees/'+$rootScope.current_user_id).success(function(response) {
            $rootScope.user_info = response["data"]["user_info"];
        });
    };

    if ($rootScope.current_user_id) {
        $rootScope.get_user_profile();
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('ProfileCtr', ['$rootScope','$scope','Employee','fileReader','$translate','$filter','checkResponse','toaster', function($rootScope,$scope, Employee,fileReader,$translate,$filter,checkResponse,toaster){
    $scope.langs = [ { name: "en",value: "English"}, { name: "de_DE", value: "German"}, { name: "fr_FR", value: "French"} ];
    $scope.set_language = function() {
        $scope.selectLang = $filter('filter')($scope.langs, { name: $rootScope.user_info.eselected_language})[0];
    }
    $scope.set_language();
});
```

Comment: check   $rootScope.user_info value in console inside run method. see whether it is there or not.

Comment: @Ved  if i put console.log inside the $http callback than it is printing the object, but if i put console.log outside the get_user_profile callback than it is printing the undefined

Comment: wait. I am working on this.

Comment: Do one thing. Define $rootScope.user_info  ouside the get_user_profile callback and initialize it to Null. than see do you get value outside the callback.

Comment: the console.log execute first and than get_user_profile callback execute.. check this one http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/797353/ca25a921bd46073f76199d72fae855d3

Comment: I forgot about this. Everything seems fine. Can you post the response data.

Comment: here is the response of api call . http://awesomescreenshot.com/02a5g3yd01

Answer (score 0):

Your `$rootScope.user_info` is defined in `$http.get` callback, which is async method. And when you enter or refresh your page, of course it runs later than you try to access `$rootScope.user_info` object. So, it's bad practice to write code like this. You have to use `callbacks` or `promises` when using async functions.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following:

1. `$rootScope.get_user_profile` makes an HTTP request that ends up taking ten minutes.
2. `$scope.set_language` is called which tries to access `$rootScope.user_info.eselected_language`, and fails.
3. Ten minutes later, the response finally comes back and sets `$rootScope.user_info`.

The problem with your code is that `3` might happen after `2`; it completely depends on the HTTP request. That's why you have the problem sometimes rather than all the time (because the time the HTTP takes is variable). You don't want it to depend on anything, you want to *guarantee* that `2` happens *after* `3`.

---

You could do the HTTP request in your controller and chain off of it like so (note: `.success` is [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

```
$http
  .get('/api/v1/employees/'+$rootScope.current_user_id)
  .then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.user_info = response["data"]["user_info"];
  })
  .then(function() {
     // $rootScope.user_info has been set
     // your code here
  })
;
```

But that wouldn't really be a good approach. You'll probably want to access your user in other places too, and repeating this structure everywhere wouldn't be very DRY.

So what you could do is you could use the [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) feature of UI router. It basically says, "don't instantiate the controller until these promises resolve". So you'd want to say, "don't instantiate the controller until the HTTP request to get my user data resolves".

Your code would look something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('yourStateHere', {
    url: '/yourUrlHere',
    resolve: {
      getUser: function($http, $rootScope) {
        $http
          .get('/api/v1/employees/' + $rootScope.current_user_id)
          .then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.user_info = response["data"]["user_info"];
          })
        ;
      }
    },
    controller: 'ControllerName'
  })
;
```

Comment: i am using $rootScope.user_info at many places in other controllers. So it is possible to use user_info if i move my http callback in resolve?

Comment: What `resolve` does is it just delays the instantiation of the controller, so you'll still be able to user `$rootScope.user_info` in these controllers.